# How to set desired location of UITextField's inputAccessoryView?

Tags: ios, uitextfield, inputaccessoryview

In order to have a button atop the keyboard with my `UITextField`, I'm doing this:

```
class MyTextField: UITextField {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        let buttonSize = CGSize(width: button.frame.size.width, height: 50)
        button.frame = CGRect(origin: button.frame.origin, size: buttonSize)
        button.backgroundColor = .orange
        button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        button.setTitle("Test", for: .normal)
        inputAccessoryView = button
    }

}
```

[image]

Although this works fine, I'd like to customize a little more the origin and size of the button here, but I can't find a way to do so. I tried this instead:

```
let buttonSize = CGSize(width: button.frame.size.width - 100, height: 50)
button.frame = CGRect(origin: button.frame.origin, size: buttonSize)
```

But the button keeps the same width. What can I do?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is that the frame of the view assigned to inputAccessoryView ignored , so create a view with transparent color and add any item to it , You can try this

```
class MyTextField: UITextField {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width:UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width-100,height: 50)
        button.backgroundColor = .orange
        button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        button.setTitle("Test", for: .normal)
        let rr = UIView()
        rr.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width:UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width,height: 50)
        rr.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear;
        inputAccessoryView = rr
        rr.addSubview(button)
    }


}
```

[image]

Comment: Good solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyTextField: UITextField {

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.frame = CGRect(x:50, y:5, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width-100,height: 50)
        button.backgroundColor = .orange
        button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        button.setTitle("Test", for: .normal)

        let aframe = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width,height: 60)
        let accessory = UIView(frame: aframe)
        accessory.backgroundColor = .clear
        accessory.addSubview(button)

        inputAccessoryView = accessory
    }

}
```